# Преобразование параметра известного на этапе компиляции в аргумент шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Пусть имеется некоторая шаблонная функция `foo` с целочисленным параметром шаблона:

```
template <int N>
void foo() {
}
```

Можно ли написать такую функцию/функциональный объект `void bar(...int n...)`, которая будет внутри себя вызывать функцию `foo<n>`, если параметр `n` может быть вычислен на этапе компиляции, и будет ошибка компиляции, если `n` не может быть вычислен.

Насколько я понимаю, такое поведение недопустимо в современных стандартах (даже включая С++17, несмотря на Class template argument deduction), но может быть есть концепты к будущим стандартам, разрешающие такое поведение?

Хак с `#define` не предлагать, разумеется.

Comment: Каково предназначение для такого гипотетического кода?

Comment: @Constructor Во-первых теоретический. А вырос он из желания иметь максимально универсальную функцию `pow(a, b) = b^a` для типов, для которых тип `b*b` не равен исходному типу `b`. Можно написать функцию с прототипом `pow<a>(b)`, но тогда это наложит ограничения на a как константу времени компиляции даже для типов, для которых это не нужно (`int`).

Comment: А зачем еще что-то писать? Можно просто вызвать `foo` и если параметр `N` не может быть вычислен на этапе компиляции, то будет ошибка...

Comment: @VTT можно посмотреть предыдущий комментарий... Синтаксис `foo<n>` всегда накладывает на `n` ограничение как на константу времени компиляции. А я хочу иметь возможность накладывать ограничение иногда.

Comment: @dortmund Может тогда в вопросе ошибка: "и будет ошибка компиляции, если n не может быть вычислен."

Comment: @VTT в вопросе нет ошибки. Просто он является более узким, чем вся решаемая задача. А комментарий просто объяняет, почему использовать foo<n> решение, которое меня не устраивает.

Comment: @dortmund Я имею ввиду, что вместо "**и будет** ошибка компиляции" наверное должно быть "**и не будет** ошибка компиляции", иначе это то поведение, которое и так возникает при вызове `foo<N>`.

Comment: @VTT я не против того, чтобы была ошибка компиляции. Для тех случаев, где я хочу иметь возможность использовать не константу времени компиляции SFINAE мне поможет выкинуть эту функцию из потенциальных кандидатов для вызова совсем.

Comment: Такого плавного перехода между run-time и compile-time, как Вы хотите, в C++ нет. Можно лишь сделать какой-то достаточно ограниченный вариант. Что-нибудь вроде этого: https://wandbox.org/permlink/XPdDJ80GWPI1NByh

Comment: А почему не просто `constexpr`?

Comment: @Qwertiy К сожалению, в стандарте в данный момент аргументы функции не могу быть constexpr. Поэтому внутри функции невозможно обращаться с параметром как с constexpr переменными. То есть да, мой вопрос был про "constexpr function parametrs". И про то, есть ли подходы к разработке и введению этого в некоторых будущих стандартах.

Comment: А почему бы просто не объявить `n` template-параметром функции `bar`?

Comment: Думаю вместо int стоит всётаки использовать enum. Тогда в аргумент будут передавать именно то значение которое в рамках  enum, если конечно через cast не будет использоваться "обходной" путь.

Comment: Для `f(...)` - нельзя, для "overload" можно, но будет либо синтаксическая ошибка либо что-то подобное.

Comment: Можно обернуть параметры в лямбду, см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1448750/312941; для различия контекста использовать `if consteval`. Если интересно такое решение, могу написать ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Для `bar(...)` нельзя, поскольку тип аргументов не "пробрасывается" через "var-arg". Но используя overload - можно, например так

```
template<typename T1> void bar(T1 a1) {
    foo(a1); // если foo обьявлена как template (как в вопросе) то так можно
    }

template<typename T1,typename T2> void bar(T1 a1,T2 a2) {
    foo(a1);
    foo(a2);
    }
// и так далее столько сколько нужно.
```

Тогда если допустили ошибку при указании типа - будет сгенерирована ошибка компиляции.

Comment: Никаких vararg'ов у ТС нет. Через многоточие он просто показал, что у `bar` есть какой-то параметр, который нужно транслировать в вызов шаблонной функции. А вот у этой вызываемой шаблонной функции аргументов как раз нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужна для этого обертка, достаточно пометить саму функцию как `constexpr`:

```
template<int N>
constexpr void foo() { /* impl */ }
```

Пример:

```
foo<10>();    // ошибки нет
foo<boo()>(); // ошибка, параметр не может быть вычислен на этапе компиляции
              // boo() - не является constexpr функцией
```

Comment: ТС хочет функционально подобную сущность `bar`, принимающую `int`, из которой можно было бы вызывать `foo` с этим интом.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, если так, то я немного не понимаю, чего хочет добиться ТС: если мы хотим взять значение аргумента и параметризовать им шаблон функции - то, кажется, ответ очевиден - так делать нельзя.

Comment: Именно это он и хочет. Но с ограничением: если значение compile-time, то почему бы его не пропихнуть в шаблон. Для рантайм - очевидно фейл.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, понял Вас, спасибо, что объяснили, в чем тут дело :)