# Использование лямбды для constexpr/consteval параметров функции

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, constexpr

В C++ параметры `constexpr/consteval` функции сами не являются `constexpr/consteval`. Однако если обернуть передачу этих параметров в лямбду, то [всё работает](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:11,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:11),source:%27consteval+auto+foo(auto+x)+%7B%0A++++return+x%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsteval+auto+bar(auto+x)+%7B%0A++++static_assert(foo(x)+%3D%3D+x)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsteval+auto+baz(auto+x)+%7B%0A++++static_assert(foo(x())+%3D%3D+x())%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++++bar(42)%3B+++++++++++++//+error:+non-constant+condition+for+static+assertion%0A++++baz(%5B%5D%7Breturn+42%3B%7D)%3B+//+OK%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```
consteval auto foo(auto x) {
    return x;
}

consteval auto bar(auto x) {
    static_assert(foo(x) == x);
}

consteval auto baz(auto x) {
    static_assert(foo(x()) == x());
}

int main(){
    bar(42);             // error: non-constant condition for static assertion
    baz([]{return 42;}); // OK
}
```

Хоть у лямбды оператор вызова и является `constexpr`, т.к. он является членом, то должен неявно принимать объект лямбды, который не является константным выражением.

**За счёт чего тогда это работает или это нелегальное использование?** Желательно с указанием на пункты стандарта.

Comment: За что минус вопросу?

Comment: Похоже, на проблему "должна  ли consteval функция компилироваться?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466245/is-compiler-allowed-to-call-an-immediate-consteval-function-during-runtime

Comment: @Chorkov не совсем понял, что именно там отвечает на мой вопрос

Comment: Лямбды по молчанию `constexpr`, если они исполняют контракт `constexpr`. Параметры функции не будут являться constant expression. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226797/will-consteval-allow-using-static-assert-on-function-arguments)

Answer (score 4):

**Короткий ответ:**

1. Потому что

```
consteval auto foo(auto x)
```

является эквивалентом

```
template<typename T> 
consteval auto foo(T x)
```

, а не

```
template<auto x> 
consteval auto foo()
```

. Потому что правило для интерпретации auto-аргументов (placeholder-type-specifier), не зависит от наличия спецификатора consteval перед функцией. См. 9.3.3.5.18

2. пример:

```
consteval void func(int n) {
    static_assert( n>=0 ); //  expression did not evaluate to a constant
}
```

должен порождать ошибку, независимо от того вызываем ли мы функцию func вообще, и с какими аргументами. см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226797/will-consteval-allow-using-static-assert-on-function-arguments
Потому что immediate function, это тоже function и проверка, что они не-illformed (т.е. что их можно скомпилировать.) производится при обработке тела функции, а не в момент вызова.

**Развернутый ответ:**

Заметим, что constexpr функции порождают по сути две функции: одну которая будет работать в run-time с произвольными аргументами, и одну которая будет работать с конкретными значениям в compile-time (immediate function).

consteval - обязаны порождать только compile-time функцию (immediate function), но требования и порядок компиляции для них, по сравнению с constexpr, неизменен. Cм. 9.2.5. [dcl.constexpr]

Есть дополнительные требования по использованию consteval, которые гарантируют, что компилятор всегда сможет вычислить результат функции как константное выражение.

Я не нашел, пункта, в котором указано что constexpr/consteval функции должны удовлетворять требованиям к обычным функциям. (Есть только ряд дополнительных требований, общих для consteval и constexpr: 9.2.5.3.) Видимо, это подразумевается, поскольку это тоже функции. Для constexpr это требование совершенно необходимо, поскольку они должны иметь возможность породить обычную (вызываемую в run-time) функцию.

Упростим ваш пример:

```
template<typename T>
consteval auto bar(T x) {
    static_assert(x == x);
}
...
bar(42);
```

При компиляции для нас значимы три стадии:

1. проверка шаблона функции (подстановка имен, независящих от типов аргументов)
2. инстанционирование шаблона для конкретного типа (суть, компиляция). Именно на этом этапе будет проверен static_asset.
3. подстановка конкретного константного значения и вычисление результата для него.

Если  стадия 2 не будет выполнена, то до 3 дело не дойдет.
Хотя продукт стадии 2 (скомпилированное тело функции), в случае consteval, нам и ненужен.

Хотя мы понимаем, что `x==x` всегда верно для всех встроенных типов (кроме double), тем не менее встроенный оператор == может вернуть конкретное значение на этапе компиляции, только если знает (на этапе компиляции) значения аргументов сравнения. Для произвольных значений аргументов, проверка того, что результат одинаков во всех случаях - разумным образом неразрешима (только перебрать все возможные комбинации аргументов). Поэтому, компилятор выдает ошибку на стадии 2. В тексте сообщения он будет ссылаться на строку `bar(42);`, поскольку конкретный тип аргумента станет известен только в этой строке, но это не стадия 3 (подстановка значения), как может показаться.

Заметим, что некоторые выражения, например `sizeof(x)`, выдадут константное значение на шаге 2, поэтому их можно использовать в static_assert.

**Почему работает с лямбдами?**
В случае лямбды, вы фактически спрятали значение внутрь типа.
Поскольку в лямбде ничего не захватывается, и возвращаемое значение ни от чего не завист, то `operator()` является constexpr. Т.е. выражением `x()` так же не зависит только от конкретного значения переданного в  функцию, также как и в случае `sizeof(x)`.

Т.е. ваше решение - легальное, но неудобное.

**Как исправить код, "чтобы работало"?**

```
template<auto x>
consteval auto bar() {
    static_assert(foo(x) == x);
}
...
bar<42>(); // ok
```

Здесь, значения x известны уже на стадии 2.

Или так:

```
consteval auto bar(auto x) {
    return foo(x) == x;
}
...
static_assert( bar(42) ); // ok
```

Здесь static_assert-проверка будет выполнена уже после стадии 3.

Answer (score 0):

`static_assert` объявление ожидает в скобках *constant expression*.

[[dcl.pre]/nt:static_assert-declaration](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.pre#nt:static_assert-declaration):

> static_assert-declaration:
>
> - static_­assert ( **constant-expression** ) ;
> - static_­assert ( constant-expression , string-literal ) ;

Однако ни в одном из случаев `static_assert(foo(x) == x)`, `static_assert(x == x)`, `static_assert(foo(x))`, `static_assert(x)` для параметра `x` типа `int` выражения в скобках не будут *constant expression*, т.к. в них выполняется *lvalue-to-rvalue* преобразование для чтения значения из *lvalue* `x`.

[[expr.const]/5.8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.const#5.8):

> An expression E is a core constant expression **unless the evaluation** of
> E, following the rules of the abstract machine, **would evaluate** one of the following :
>
> - ...
> - **an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion** <strike>unless it is applied to</strike>
>
>   - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to an object that is usable in constant expressions, or
>   - a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of E;
> - ...

[[expr.const]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.const#11):

> **A constant expression is either** a glvalue **core constant expression**
> that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant
> expression (as defined below), **or** a prvalue **core constant expression**
> whose value satisfies the following constraints:
>
> - ...

В случае же лямбды с пустым списком захвата это преобразование не надо, т.к. она содержит оператор преобразования. И оператор преобразования, и оператор вызова при этом будут `constexpr`.

[[expr.prim.lambda]/closure-11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.prim.lambda#closure-11):

> **The conversion function** or conversion function template **is** public,
> **constexpr**, non-virtual, non-explicit, const, and has a non-throwing exception specification. ...

[[expr.prim.lambda]/closure-4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.prim.lambda#closure-4):

> **The function call operator** or any given operator template specialization **is a constexpr function if** either the corresponding
> lambda-expression's parameter-declaration-clause is followed by
> constexpr or consteval, or **it satisfies the requirements for a
> constexpr function**.

[[dcl.constexpr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.constexpr#3):

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following
> requirements:
>
> - its return type (if any) shall be a literal type;
> - each of its parameter types shall be a literal type;
> - it shall not be a coroutine;
> - if the function is a constructor or destructor, its class shall not have any virtual base classes;
> - its function-body shall not enclose
>
> > - a goto statement,
> > - an identifier label,
> > - a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static or thread storage duration.

Касательно вашего замечания:

> т.к. он является членом, то должен неявно принимать объект лямбды,
> который не является константным выражением

Использование `this` в `constexpr` функции, являющейся частью рассматриваемого *core constant expression*, не делает это выражение не *core constant expression*.

[[expr.const]/5.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.const#5.1):

> **An expression E is a core constant expression** <strike>unless the evaluation of
> E, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following</strike>:
>
> - *this*, **except in a constexpr function that is being evaluated as part of E**;
> - ...